# How to apply colors to newly generated cards in memory game of JS

Tags: javascript

I did an array with 25 random colors
how I "paint" them with the colors generated

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    function generateRandomColor() {
        const hexValues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
        let randomNum = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            randomNum += hexValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return `#${randomNum}`
    }

    var grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        grid.innerHTML += '<div class="card" ></div>';
       

    }    
    function generateArrayOfColors() { 
        var colors = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 25; i ++) { 

            colors.push(generateRandomColor());

        }
        return colors;
    }


    console.log(generateArrayOfColors())
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 
        var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
        
        cards[i].style.backgroundColor = ??;
    } 

});
```

expected something like cards[i].style.backgroundColor =  generateArrayOfColors(); to work

Comment: What is the last loop supposed to do? Do you actually want to assign each color to a card 50 times continuously?

Comment: Hi 
I want once to every card of the 50 with one of the colors returned by generateArrayOfColors()

Comment: I get that, but what is `50`? 50 cards, or 50 times? `generateArrayOfColors()` only returns a list of 25 colors, so if there are 50 cards, you'll need more colors, or assign some or all of them to at least 2 or more cards.

Comment: I do a memory game with 50 cards , each 2 cards painted with same random color

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo operator `%` to fold the indexes of `colorArray` in your loop. When the index of your cards is less than 25 you will get the current index. When index is larger than 25 you will get the reminder of division i/colorArray.length so that the value will stay in the range of colors array.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
function generateRandomColor() {
    const hexValues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    let randomNum = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        randomNum += hexValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return `#${randomNum}`
}

var grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

for (var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    grid.innerHTML += '<div class="card"></div>';
}    

function generateArrayOfColors() { 
    var colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) { 
        colors.push(generateRandomColor());
    }
    return colors;
}

var colorArray = generateArrayOfColors();
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) { 
    cards[i].style.backgroundColor = colorArray[i % colorArray.length];
}
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
 }

  .card {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="grid"></div>
```